# Android Retrofit2 passing email through @Formurlencoded converts the @ sign to %40

Tags: android

I am trying to make a post request through Retrofit2 in which email is sent as key value pair (not as POJO like using @Body with Retrofit2), by using this @FormUrlEncoded I am able to hit the API but "@" sign gets converted to "%40" and same case for any other special symbols. Can anyone help sending the email to API server using Retrofit2 without using the @Body in Retrofit2.
My code is as below:

```
public RetroWrapper (Context context, Object listener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listener = listener;
        OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder();
        builder.readTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        builder.connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
            builder.addInterceptor(interceptor);
        }

        builder.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
//                Request request = chain.request().newBuilder().addHeader("Content-Type", "text/json").build();
                Request request = chain.request().newBuilder().addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded").build();
                return chain.proceed(request);
            }
        });

        OkHttpClient client = builder.build();

        retrofit= new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BuildConfig.WEBSERVICE_BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client).build();

    }
public void loginCheckDirectPost(Map<String,String> stringStringMap){
        RetroServices.RetroServicePostLoginReqDirectPost retroSrvcGetFeeds = retrofit.create(RetroServices.RetroServicePostLoginReqDirectPost.class);
        Call<PostLoginResp> getFeedsCall = retroSrvcGetFeeds.CALL(stringStringMap);
        getFeedsCall.enqueue((Callback<PostLoginResp>) listener);
    }




    public interface RetroServicePostLoginReqDirectPost{
            @FormUrlEncoded
            @POST("token")
            Call<PostLoginResp> CALL(@FieldMap Map<String, String> params);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your content is being URL encoded , so "@" becomes %40.

You will need to modify it at the server to decode %40 into "@";

Comment: Agreed to that but that is what the challenge is.
I have already used the content-type as application/x-www-form-urlencoded but no success! 
Also I donot want the server to do changes as this thing could also be required in future how to send these special charecters directly through post.

Comment: Exactly ,replace it ""text/json" . Dont use urlencoded as the content type.